# Align footer text to center - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently using inline styling to align the text inside the footer to center.Where do I make the change in bootstrap.css? What is the correct approach? A new class in bootstrap.css and then use it in the footer or is there a bootstrap class that I need to edit.This is the html I have right now.

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p style="text-align:center">&copy; 2017 - core Inc. - Score </p>
        </br>
        <p style="text-align:center">contact:abc@core.com</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: does `<footer class="text-center">` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use inline css, you can use bootstrap classes. 
Hoping that is bootstrap 3, you can find more [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment)

You can use it like this:

```
  <footer class="text-center">
      <div>
          <p>&copy; 2017 - core Inc. - Score </p>
      </div>        
      <div>
          <a href="mailto:abc@core.com">contact:abc@core.com</a>
      </div>
 </footer>
```

Comment: Thanks that works ! I need to wait 9 more mins to accept it as answer.

Comment: No problem. Just recheck please, I improved the answer.

Comment: Just gave a vote up.. but why would you need to add `div` before those `p` tags?

Comment: I thought that <p> has display inline by default. That can be removed, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has handy [text alignment helper classes](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment).

```
<p class="text-center">&copy; 2017 - core Inc. - Score </p>
```

Also, get rid of that `br` between paragraphs. If you need a space, apply margin.